# Why is sum of area of pieces equal the whole?

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, axioms

We automatically assume total area of a shape is sum of area of individual sub pieces. How do one define area and build it up purely axiomatically. Without say getting to measure theory? The difficulties arise because individual pieces need to have area and not some other n-dimensional volume concept. Is there a rigorous definition for area and other n-dim volumes?

Comment: For axioms, see [Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area#Formal_definition).

Comment: More specifically: If S and T are in M [where M is collection of special kind of plane figures] then so are S ∪ T and S ∩ T, and also a(S∪T) = a(S) + a(T) − a(S∩T).

Comment: You ask how we do it formally without getting into measure theory. But...but.. measure theory IS the formalisation of ..well.. measure. Among others, also area.

Comment: Alvin, Yeah, is there a simpler one?

Comment: When you formalise the idea of area, you do it in such a way that the sum of the areas of the pieces is equal to the sum of the whole - certainly for the kind of pieces you are interested in. The consequences of such a definition, encompassing the good properties we want, we call measure theory. The fact that we have to be careful about which pieces we allow is illustrated by the Banach-Tarski Paradox https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox . As with set theory, once we get beyond elementary applications, we need to formalise what we are doing with some care.

Comment: Thanks, yeah the having to define what is measurable is what makes axiomatic approach non trivial.